# No matching user found - OAuthException Error in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My perfectly working chat application all of a received these errors, without having altered any of the settings, when sending chat messages:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found",  
 "type":"OAuthException",
 "code":100,
  "error_subcode":2018001,
  "fbtrace_id":"xxxxx"}
}
```

I went my application settings -> Messenger -> Settings and created a new token for the page my chatbot is associated with. That fixed it. I used tokens before over many month without having to refresh the token.

I understand that tokens expire, but I was under the impression that page tokens for facebook messenger are stable until they are revoked. What's the automatic procedure for getting a new token, do I get a callback when my token is about to expire? I was looking in the documentation of the facebook messenger but couldn't find any solution or suggestion for my problem. What do I need to do?

Comment: There is no automatic procedure, and you don’t get a notification either. You can check the expiry of an existing token though, by debugging it (see Facebook login docs.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you, it's strange that FB doesn't indicate that in the messenger docs that those tokens need to be periodically refreshed which let me to believe that they don't expire. thanks again.

Comment: They don’t mention it, because it isn’t true. Extended page tokens do not have a default expiry.

Comment: @CBroe well, that's what I thought. do you know under which circumstances token's expire?

Comment: When the user who granted it changes their password, or the app secret is reset. Also when the user gets caught in a login check that requires extra verification, I think.